# Why the names of the actions "Mail to Self" and "Save to Files" on the screen "Share" may not be translated into Russian language

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

Good afternoon!
Please, tell me, why the names of the actions "Mail to Self" and "Save to Files" on the screen "Share" may not be translated into Russian language?
The language on the device is Russian, the buttons "Copy" and "Edit actions" are translated.
Added to info.plist "Localized resources can be mixed" = YES (without this setting the buttons “Copy” and “Edit action” were not translated), but for “Mail to Self” and “Save to Files” this does not work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPoib.jpg)

Comment: Might be an iOS bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help Claude31 in the ticket https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/667963?login=true&page=1#649866022 a solution was found.
In info.plist "Localization native development region" had "$ (DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)".
After installing "ru" everything was translated.